# opensuse 12.2: yast misconfiguration ldap server

Tags: openldap, opensuse

i have a very simple question. I used Yast to configure openldap. It worked. Then I had to change the certificates for SSL/TSL support. I did this trough Yast. However, I gave the path towards the wrong files and as a results, I can't start ldap server anymore. Could someone tell me how i can change the paths to these certificates. Which config files do i need to change?
I looked in etc/openldap/slapd.conf, /etc/openldap/ldap.conf, etc/ldap.conf, but it seems i can't find it anywhere.

We are working with opensuse 12.2
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I looked in `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf`, `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`,
>   `etc/ldap.conf`, but it seems i can't find it anywhere.

Because it uses the [newer style](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html). You can search throughout the `/etc/openldap` directory for `tls` string:

```
# grep -lir tls /etc/openldap/
/etc/openldap/ldap.conf
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif

# grep -i tls /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config.ldif
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/ca/ca.crt
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/ca/server.csr
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/ca/server.key
```